# Manter o SELECT OPTION selecionado após a atualização

Tags: php

Estou usando um SELECT que atualiza automaticamente a página após a seleção. Todavia ele retorna com o SELECT na posição inicial, quando o desejável seria que a opção selecionada já viesse setada no controle.

Encontrei um código na internet mas não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar:

```
echo "<option value='premorc.php?fnc=". $fnc . "&ans=" . $linha . "&bandorc=" . $band . "'  if ($bandorc==$band){ echo 'SELECTED';} '>" . $bandeira . "</option>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `if` que tem no `echo` está a ser interpretado como texto.

```
echo "<option value='premorc.php?fnc=".$fnc."&ans=".$linha."&bandorc=".$band."'  if ($bandorc==$band){ echo 'SELECTED';} '>" . $bandeira . "</option>";
//----------------------------------------------------- faltou concatenar aqui ^
```

Sugiro no entanto que simplifique. Pode usar variáveis diretamente dentro de aspas duplas `"` sem ter que concatenar com `.`.

Pode sendo assim transformar o `echo` que tem em:

```
echo "<option value='premorc.php?fnc=$fnc&ans=$linha&bandorc=$band' ".($bandorc==$band?"selected":"").">$bandeira</option>";
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/DkAoSe)